# Rpm gets drop in cng while changing the gear

Tags: hyundai, rpm, accent

I have a Hyundai Accent 2014 with CNG fitment. For 3 months I have not been able to resolve my problem as my RPM drops when I change the gear. I don't know what is happening with it. I showed to CNG mechanic and even garage person, but didn't get a solution. They said to clean the throttle body, change plug wires, and also coil. Tried with every thing but no use. Please can anyone help me? I'm in a bit trouble, as no one is getting the proper solution for this and hence I am facing this issue since for the last 3 months.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!